# if $x<y<z$, is either $A$ or $B$ necessarily larger given that $A=(x+y+z)/3$ and $B=(A+z)/2$?

Tags: inequality

A student attempted to compute the average,$A$, of $x,y$ and $z $ by computing the average of $x$ and  $y$, and then computing the average of that result with $z$. The student's final result was $B$. if $x<y<z$, is either $A$ or $B$ necessarily larger ?

**My attempt**

Writing everything in terms of equations I have

$$ \cfrac{x+y+z}{3} =A $$
$$\cfrac{x+y+2z}{4}=B  $$

I thought at this point to use AM-GM inequality since I am concerned with sums here and I've got (for $A$) 
$$A \ge (xyz)^{1/3}$$

using  AM-GM inequality I have $$ B \ge \frac{3}{4}  \left(2(xyz)\right)^{1/3}$$

Now I am quite stuck ,I don't know how to simplify in order to have some form of the type $P > Q $ in terms of $A,B$

---

A more naive approach I've tried was to simply rearrange the averages and get $3A+2z=6B$ but this doesn't look quite useful I guess.

Comment: You wrote out the equations incorrectly. It should be $A=\frac{x+y+z}{3}$ and $B=\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}+z}{2}=\frac{x+y+2z}{4}$.

Comment: I think you meant to say $$B=\frac{\frac{x+y}{2}+z}{2}$$ because you wrote *by computing the average of $x$ and $y$, and then computing the average of that result with $z$ *

Comment: yes let me fix.(Sorry !)

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes,I hope everything is fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to compare them is to look at $A-B$ because lots of things cancel :

$$A-B=\frac{x+y+x}{3}-\frac{x+y+2z}{4}=\frac{x+y-2z}{12}$$

But $z>x$ and $z>y$ so $x+y-2z=(x-z)+(y-z)<0$

This means that $A<B$ .

Comment: That is creative.Thanks for the time ;)